# Building custom OrderBy expression in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, sql-order-by

I have generic EntityFramework class that works with database context. This class is used to Get data from any table.

```
public async Task<List<TResult>> GetAsync<T, TResult>(
            Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector,
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
            IEnumerable<string> paths = null
            )
            where T : class, IEntityWithName<int>
        {
            var query = Entities<T>();

            if (predicate != null)
                query = query.Where(predicate);

            if (paths != null)
                foreach (var path in paths)
                    query = query.Include(path);

            var resultQuery = query
                .OrderBy(iten => item.Path.Path) // <- I need this part to work. 
                .ThenBy(item => item.FileName)  // Sort by Path first, then by FileName
                .Select(selector);

                var items = await resultQuery.ToListAsync();

                return items;
            }
        }

File table
   ID filename PathID
   1  dog1.jpg  1 
   2  dog2.jpg  2

Path table
   ID Path             
   1  \\folderPath1\           
   2  \\folderPath2\
```

My questions  is how can I provide OrderBy parameter, so that results are   ordered by Path first, which is stored in Path table of course.

Problem I face is that "Path" entity is not included always in the result. That's why I need check first, and then build a custom expression for OrderBy clause.

Comment: You don't need to include a path to use it for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ dynamic query library which allows for string parameters in orderby, where clauses, and other operations.

.OrderBy("columnname")

Answer (score 0):

You can put a check in your OrderBy() clause to check if item.Path.Path isNullOrEmpty:

```
var resultQuery = query
            .OrderBy(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Path.Path))
            .ThenBy(item => item.FileName)
            .Select(selector);
```